# Windows 10 Anyconnect VPN - no way to use default gateway on remote network

Tags: windows-10, vpn

A while back Anyconnect VPN used to work fine on Windows 10, with computers having both remote access to the target network and internet access.

Now it seems there's a gateway problem and computers no longer have internet access.

The option "use default gateway on remote network" does no longer exist in the IPv4 properties of the CISCO Anyconnect adapter.

I have attempted to enable split tunneling via powershell with something like "Set-VpnConnection -Name "Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client Connection" -SplitTunneling $True -PassThru -AllUserConnection" but it does not find the VPN name identifier.

Is there an alternate non-powershell way to enable the adapter to use the default gateway or any other way to make internet access work correctly again ?

From the CISCO side I can make this work but I'm interested on a solution on the windows side.